# Is there a way to organise the right hand sidebar in 2.8?

Tags: interface, add-on, customization, panel

As all plugins/add-ons in Blender 2.8 are now added to the right hand sidebar, I find that mine is now becoming so full it's impossible to read what each add-on is.
Is there a way to better organise the strip of add-on names, maybe make them 2 deep?[image: overflowing sidebar]

Comment: Sounds more like a feature request

Comment: Sorry if there is no way to currently do this then yes I guess it is a feature request.